# In Swift (iOS app), when do I need to use other integer types?

Tags: swift

I saw there are many integer types in Swift other than `Int`, for example:

```
Int8
UInt32
uint_fast16_t
```

I can understand their definitions but I am wondering when/why I should use them instead of `Int`?

For example, `Int8` is a 8-bit integer. From my understanding, unless I want to save some memory, why bother using it?

PS. I am using Swift for iOS app development.

Comment: You should always use Int, Double and String. Only use other integers  where they are mandatory.

Comment: Sure, but my question is to know when/where is necessary? It would be great if you can give further explanation. Thanks.

Comment: let x:Int = 3; arc4random_uniform(UInt32(x))

Comment: I now understand what you meant "when they are mandatory". Question is why this function uses `UInt32` instead of `Int` while I should always use `Int` . Would like to know the reasoning behind.

Comment: Why the method arc4random_uniform uses UInt32 ? Because it will only allow you to input positive values(unsigned integer type)

Comment: so why can't I use UInt32 when my function allows only positive input values?

Comment: If I use Int8, doesn't it mean I try to save some memory I use? If not, please let me know further explanation. It seems you mean I should just use Int unless I need to use other types of integer. And it's exactly what I am trying to understand.

Comment: My take is that `arc4random_uniform()` uses `UInt32` instead of `Int` because it exists before/outside the Swift programming language. `Int` is a Swift construct (internally a `struct`, perhaps?), not a native type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same way that Swift has other aspects *underneath the covers* such as *pointers*, these other numeric types are there for *specific purposes*. Some of these purposes are:

- Integration with a C library. There may be specific C types that a C library requires and these types allow you to pass data to/from the libraries
- Very large scientific datasets. Float (32-bit single precision floating point) allows you to keep twice the elements in memory in the same space as Double at some sacrifice to accuracy. Multi-day global environmental datasets from satellite sensors, astronomy datasets, etc. have huge space requirements.
- Half-precision floating point requires *half* the storage and bandwidth of Float and can be pertinent for some graphics applications
- Vector processing using the Accelerate library. Accelerate functions work with a variety of numeric types and 32-bit single precision accuracy *may* be acceptable for the task you wish to accomplish.

Comment: Today I wanted to code an id variable and I know the id is between 1 to 20. In this case, should I just use `Int8`? or it's too trivial I can just ignore considering the target environment (iOS devices)? Or maybe I should ask this in a separate question?

Comment: I would just use `Int`. Using 8-bit integers is just making you more likely to have overflow problems and any memory saving will be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have mentioned, sometimes there is a need for interoperability with some external (C) library, or you just want to put constraints on the values allowed/detect overflow.

As an example, consider this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-miari/ee40e138d6188a741269) I made some time ago:

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor
{
    convenience init(
        redByte   red:UInt8,
        greenByte green:UInt8,
        blueByte  blue:UInt8,
        alphaByte alpha:UInt8
        )
    {
        self.init(
            red:   CGFloat(red  )/255.0,
            green: CGFloat(green)/255.0,
            blue:  CGFloat(blue )/255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(alpha)/255.0
        )
    }
}
```

...which is a convenient short-hand for creating a UIColor instance when you know the values of components you want to use as 'bytes' (integers in the 0-255 range), instead of 'normalized' floats (i.e., 0.0 ~ 1.0).

Using the specific type `UInt8` instead of Swift's native `Int` enforces the policy (and clarifies the intent) that arguments should be unsigned, 8 bit integer values.

Comment: _Off-topic, I find the gist particularly useful since tools used by designers (e.g. Adobe Illustrator) typically report color component values in this format._

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309):

> Use the Int type for all general-purpose integer constants and variables 
>   in your code, even if they are known to be non-negative. [...] Use
>   other integer types only when they are specifically needed for the
>   task at hand, because of explicitly-sized data from an external
>   source, or for performance, memory usage, or other necessary
>   optimization. Using explicitly-sized types in these situations helps
>   to catch any accidental value overflows and implicitly documents the
>   nature of the data being used.

Comment: For "performance" & "memory usage" purposes, any further comments/answers on this?